# My Discord python music bot gets an error when asked to play

Tags: python, discord.py

I would appreciate the help in narrowing down this issue.

My Discord Bot will run in my python environment without errors initially. However, when I try and enter a command to stream a song from youtube, I'll get the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/DiscordMusicBot/music.py", line 25, in play
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'stop'
```

I believe I have everything setup right as I have followed [this Youtube creators tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHZlvRr9KxM).

Here is my main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)



client.run("MY_TOKEN_PLACED_HERE_REMOVED_FOR_OBVIOUS_REASONS")
```

Here is my music.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  
  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
  
  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_option': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("paused ")

  @commands.command()
  async def resume(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("resume ")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

The goal is to be able to play songs in my discord channel since Rythm Bot and Groove Bot went down.

Cheers,

Comment: I've watched the *whole* video, and it's honestly total and utter garbage. The error simply means that the `ctx.voice_client` attribute is `None`, and that means that the bot is not connected to a voice channel.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx, url:str):
    if (ctx.author.voice):
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()

        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'preferredcodec': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'webm',
                'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
        }

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([url])
        for file in os.listdir("./"):
            if file.endswith(".webm"):
                os.rename(file, "song.webm")

        source = FFmpegPCMAudio('song.webm')
        player = voice.play(source)
        await ctx.send("music is playing")


    else:
        await ctx.send("you are not in voice channel")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Curious though, how would I put in into the current code. Or are you advising that I create a new file and place this in it and that is what you meant by "use this". Thanks again for taking the time to help me out!